# Markdown application for mac ox ? github compatible?

Tags: macos, markdown

I am looking for a markdown editor for mac os x. There seems to be so many around.

Ideally one that is compatible with github MD

Anybody can recommend one that allows preview, and with really good functionality and kept up to date and frequent updates.

Its not important if its pay or free..

Thanks in advance

The question being presented as a duplicate, is out of date, the program they suggest hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: I've added a bounty to the original questions to encourage people to provide up to date answers.

Comment: Martin: I've [added an answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/128196/37797) for Mou — it has a GitHub theme which should be perfect.  cc @patrix