# How to export/backup Notes in macOS in one go

Tags: macos, backup, notes.app, evernote

I have a lot of Notes on my machine which I don't want to loose. It's not logical to export them one by one. I don’t have space for iCloud to sync them and wish for a different tool even if I had space.

I learned that I could backup `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes` but I am not really sure if this would be helpful. This is what I get as for this directory.

```
$ du -sh ./*
4.0K    ./Library
256K    ./NoteStore.sqlite
 32K    ./NoteStore.sqlite-shm
3.0M    ./NoteStore.sqlite-wal
```

I am running macOS Mojave.

Is there any way to export them in one go, which would make me either use them on my new <ac when I get one?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/438361/229437

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a third-party app called [Notes Exporter](http://writeapp.net/notesexporter/) to export all notes in one go. After granting access to the Notes data, the app exports each individual note as a separate text file in the location of your choosing.

The only limitation being that you'll need to re-import them one by one if you wish to use them on a new machine.

A better and much simpler approach, if you have the necessary storage space available would be to use iCloud to sync them to the new machine.

**Note**: No affiliation whatsoever to the developer of the app.

Comment: Amazing! that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I found with the latest Notes app on Catalina I could import all notes in one go by selecting all notes from the explorer, rather than one by one.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema is there any app for windows such as Notes Exporter ? I am trying to copy notes from iphone ios10 to pc.Thanks

Comment: @Nimesh Neema How can one parse the image files which were exported in plain text..?

Comment: I have so much and important information in Notes and this app from 2014 doesn't seem enough trustworthy to give access permissions

Comment: It converts the notes to html which, on import to the other side is rendered as pure HTML so not usable.

Comment: @nvs0000 you could perhaps use Ghostscript. But it is annoying....

Answer (score 32):

I copied the three files `NoteStore.sqlite`, `NoteStore.sqlite-shm`, and `NoteStore.sqlite-wal` from `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes` of one Mac to another and my notes appear there now. All my notes were there, albeit half a day out of sync.

Comment: can we do the samething for iphone devices ?

Comment: If your notes contain images, then you need to copy Media and Previews folders from path group.com.apple.notes/Accounts/LocalAccount

Comment: How to keep the existing notes in the other system if we replaced all the folder?
I got all the notes from one to another,, but current notes in the other system are not showing up. i backed up the files in the location to another though

Answer (score 13):

Another great third party app is [Exporter](http://falcon.star-lord.me/exporter/). It exports as markdown and keeps both folders and attachments.

Comment: This app is great! It was exactly what I wanted. Even creates all of the folder structure, resets note timestamps and can be used to re-export notes without creating duplicates. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me is:

- Finder > Go > Go to Folder > paste this

  ```
  ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes
  ```
- Select all files > Right click > Share > AirDrop to the device
- Go to the same directory on the other device
- Paste the files there (replace similar file name)
- Quit and restart Notes App

Comment: It's probably safer to close Notes on both computers before doing this.

Comment: Perfect solution!  This worked when moving notes from Mojave to Monterey via AirDrop.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Fast, precise, and FREE :).

Comment: How to keep the existing notes in the other system if we replaced all the folder?

Answer (score 1):

#### This should definitely Help

###### THE PROBLEM

This is one of the most sought answers for Mac users. I didn't find any of the answers attempting to solve directly. Neither did I want to use some third-party apps.

Also, when we have fewer notes, maybe, we can copy-paste but what if our whole learnings/sample codes and many more things are there in notes?

Also, copy-paste doesn't take care of many things, for example, date on while it was created maintains the order or notes, those metadata will be simply lost if you copy-paste.

Secondary, If you try to copy-paste the notes from the location it is stored, it's not guaranteed, that your backup will definitely work. maybe you copied the wrong directory, or maybe notes on newer a Mac/different system doesn't work. We can take that risk.

##### THE SOLUTION

**This solution goes through iCloud.**

Don't worry, this is the fastest and reliable solution, and will work for almost all of your cases. The setup won't take more than 5 mins.

1. You definitely might be having iCloud account. if not go to **System Preferences** > **iCloud** > **Create Apple ID**.

[image: iCloud Preference Pane on macOS]

2. Then, **Login** into the iCloud account.
3. Then, Open Notes app. Go to **Notes** > **Preference**. Change default account to **iCloud**

**There may be chances that you don't see you iCloud account in Notes.**

- So, for that Open Mail app.
- Go to mail > preference > account and activate the iCloud account.
- Now, go to Notes app, and you should see `iCloud` in folder pane in left side.

**Wait, there are chances that you still don't see the `iCloud` in notes app.** That's the issue.

- Then, you can try logging out of iCloud from iCloud in System Preferences.
- Go to `Mail` app.
- Now, try signing into it by providing your icloud email and password.
- As soon as you enter correct credetnials and is verified, you will get this pop up,

[image]

- Here you, make sure to check the checkbox `Notes`.
- Then, click proceed.
- Now restart Notes app.
- You will see `iCloud` in left pane where all folders are there.

**Now, main part:**

- You have to create a folder in `iCloud` in Notes, with the same name for notes folders that you have in `On My Mac`.
- Go the the Notes folder and in click on any note in second column.
  Then press `Command+A` for select all. and then, right click > Move to > iCloud > <same_folder_name>.
- Repeat, the same for all you local folders in Mac Notes.
- Done.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a separate note folder
2. Move your notes you want to export
3. Share that folder with another account via Mail (preferable) or via AirDrop
4. If via email - accept the share by following the link
5. Wait for some time and newly shared folder will appear on a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Notes.app saves its files to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV7.storedata`. Attachments to notes are saved in `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/` (citation/verification needed).

`NotesV7.storedata` is an SQLite database, so you would need to interact with and scriptable reformat that data in a different format, accordingly.

MacOS offers some Notes scripting options through scripting applications like Scriptable.

All in all, it is surprisingly inconvenient to just dump your notes en masse for import into some other notes or document app. It seems interacting with the SQL database directly would be the most direct way to programmatically export the data.