# How do I backup all the notes on my mac at once?

Tags: backup, notes.app

I have over 100 notes on my Mac from this year but stupidly I didn't put them on my I cloud as I had though it posed a securaty risk but I think I was being overly carful/paranoid.

I want to make sure there backed up encase anything happends to my Mac.

I satered moveing them manualy but I'm "lazy" so I dont want to have to move over 100 + notes manualy.

Is there a way to copy them all over at once?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357495/how-to-export-backup-notes-in-macos-in-one-go - Will this work ?

Comment: @NimeshNeema: I shared the same link with your solution :)

Comment: Thanks it should do I didnt see that question.

Comment: @Udhy If you find an existing answer on the site that answers a newly posted question, please consider casting a close vote and mark the question as duplicate by specifying the question's ID.