# How to export iOS/macOS/icloud Notes

Tags: windows, ios-appstore, ms-office, notes.app

Does anyone know how to export all my Notes in one go?
I have replaced my Macbook Pro with a Windows laptop.
It would be handy to be able to view my notes in Outlook Notes or OneNote or any other note app really. (I do find OneNote slow to load on my iPhone).

I know I can log on to icloud.com but I would rather export the notes as long term I may move to an Android phone.

I found a few articles possibly using TochPad but that only allows you to export it doesn't show you how to import.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to export/backup Notes in macOS in one go](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357495/how-to-export-backup-notes-in-macos-in-one-go?rq=1)

Comment: NotesExporter as described in link given by @agarza

Answer (score 0):

If you are on macOS I would take a look at AppleScript for this.
`/System/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app`

With a little research you can write a script that will enumerate every note and save to a file.

Within AppleScript Shift-Command-O will open Dictionaries for every application. Type "Note" and select "Choose". You will see what AppleScript can do with the Notes Application.

To get you started take a look at what this script does in AppleScript:

```applescript
tell application "Notes"
    set AllNotes to (get notes as list)
    AllNotes
end tell
```

Check out [this page](https://bear.app/faq/Import%20&%20export/Migrate%20from%20Apple%20Notes/) for some hints/solution as well.