# Importing Notes

Tags: macos, notes.app

As discussed in this question, [How to export/backup Notes in macOS in one go](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357495/how-to-export-backup-notes-in-macos-in-one-go/465245#465245), I exported the Notes data using [Exporter](http://falcon.star-lord.me/exporter/). Now I can't find out the way to import those notes back to the Notes app. The import function only imports an empty folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked in *File > Import To Notes...*?

Comment: Yes, it only seems to import an empty folder. 

From the import, I can't select the actual note files, which has extension .md